# Cannot produce the bibliography with bibunit

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, bibunits

I am trying to generate a specific bibliography for each section. Latex is producing 1 .aux file per section (i.e., in this case it produces 3 .aux file).

I can produce a .pdf, but the citation do not appear (there's only a "?").

[image: error when introductin citations]

I believe the issue could be in the way I compile the data but I can't figure out how to "bibtex on all these .aux files" as written on this webpage: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document

I am using the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits} 
\defaultbibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\defaultbibliography{/Users/Valerian/Dropbox/Mes_fichiers/PhD/15_Bibliography/1_Bibliography_bib/library} 

\begin{document}

\bibliographyunit[\section]

\section*{section 1}
Some text this guy said \cite{Adler2013}.
\putbib

\section*{section 2}
other text this gurl said \cite{Droney1996}.
\putbib

\section*{section 3}
other text the dog said \cite{Ceballos2011}.
\putbib

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I never used `bibunits`, but it's easy to have bibliographies per section with `biblatex`.

Comment: on my system this produce three aux-files: `bu1.aux`, `bu2.aux` and `bu3.aux`. You should then call in a terminal `bibtex bu1` followed by `bibtex bu2` and `bibtex bu3`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Thanks! I followed you advice and I can get the bibliography per section! However, the citations within the text still have a "[?]"